# PyCharm opens the same project on a new project creation every time

Tags: pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I have this project called `RhymerFinal` I've been working on.

Now, every time I want to create a New Project in PyCharm it opens the `RhymerFinal` every time.

- When I open another existing project, it works fine.
- It is only when I try to open a completely new Project.
- It does change the name of the window to the new project I chose on creation.

I tried so far:

1. Invalidate/Restart Caches
2. Closing `RhymerFinal` and using the GUI menu to 'Create New Project'
3. Removing `RhymerFinal` from the Project View.
4. Open Multiple Projects (it just opens `RhymerFinal` all the time).
5. Searching the web for random solutions I gambled on.

Can anyone clarify what am I doing wrong? I have the most updated PyCharm Professional version with a license.

[image]

Comment: First time I see something weird like this... I suggest: 1) Delete that project from the disk (backup into some 7z/whatever archive first) 2) Ensure that you have no references to it anywhere in IDE settings. See if that will help. 3) If not -- search through IDE config files (on Windows it would typically be in `C:\Users\USERNAME\.PyCharm2017.1\config`) and delete references there (make backup first).

Comment: 4) If still the same -- consider deleting the config folder completely and start from scratch (you may recover most of the settings from backup -- especially the neutral things like Keymap/External Tools/Live Templates/Color Schema/Code Style etc.)

Comment: Thanks ! #4 helped and solved the issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved By @LazyOne.

> If still the same -- consider deleting the config folder completely
>   and start from scratch (you may recover most of the settings from
>   backup -- especially the neutral things like Keymap/External
>   Tools/Live Templates/Color Schema/Code Style etc.)